# Como puedo poner diferentes botones en un Jtable Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero generar diferentes botones en un jtable los cuales no se repitan

**Básicamente como se ve en la imagen**, quiero hacer botones según cada icono
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eh estado revisando y solo encuentro como crear un botón y se repita en una columna, en este caso creo que necesitaría que fuera por filas pero que no en todas las columnas.

Si alguien tiene una idea de como podría hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Estuve investigando y no encontré como hacer lo que quería pero como la tabla es fija la hice con jPanels y jLabels, solo me costo un poco ajustarlos para que al cambiar el tamaño no se desordenen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Buenas, Jair, bienvenido al sitio. Es correcto contestarse uno mismo a las preguntas pero deberías poner el código que has usado y explicarlo para que sea de utilidad para todos. No es necesario que copies todo tu código sino solo un ejemplo reproducible sencillo, una tabla con dos columnas donde en la segunda se muestre un JLabel clickable o algo así. Con la imagen que has puesto no se puede sacar mucho.